# Can the target of Nature's Wrath (Channel Divinity) use an action to attempt to free itself?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, conditions

An Oath of Ancients Paladin may use her Channel Divinity class feature to apply Nature's Wrath:

> **Nature's Wrath**: As an action, you can cause spectral vines to spring up and reach for a creature within 10 feet of you that you can see. The creature must succeed on a Strength or Dexterity saving throw (its choice) or be restrained. While restrained by the vines, the creature repeats the saving throw at the end of each of its turns. On a success, it frees itself and the vines vanish.

If a creature fails the initial save and becomes restrained, can it use its action to attempt to free itself on subsequent turns (similar to how a grappled creature can use its action to attempt to escape the grapple)?

Or is it only allowed to escape by passing the save at the end of its turn(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Things do what they say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637); you cannot use an action to try again

The feature does not allow a creature to escape the restrained condition as an action. This is similar to the [*hold person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hold-person) spell which states:

> Choose a humanoid that you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be paralyzed for the duration. **At the end of each of its turns**, the target can make another Wisdom saving throw. On a success, the spell ends on the target.

It, like Nature's Wrath, does not allow any other way to escape the conditions applied.

Compare this to escaping a [grapple](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) which states:

> A Grappled creature **can use its action to escape.** To do so, it must succeed on a Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check contested by your Strength (Athletics) check.

---

Sidenote: I am not aware of any feature that allows you to make a save *both* at the end of your turn *and* as an action on your turn, but assuming one exists I'd hope it has different wording.